# how to launch powershell as another user

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server-2007

Currently if I manually connect to my admin windows account and launch this code, it works fine, but if someone that does not have admin credentials, the "enable-mailbox does not work because it cannot find the database. I did some research and it is because he does not have the permissions. Is there any way to run this code as another user providing the username and password??

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSSnapInException ex;
            powershell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(
                "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out ex);
            if (ex != null)
                throw ex;
            powershell.AddScript(". $env:ExchangeInstallPath\\bin\\RemoteExchange.ps1");
            powershell.AddScript("Connect-ExchangeServer -auto");
            powershell.Invoke();
            powershell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            powershell.Commands.Clear();
            powershell.AddCommand("Enable-Mailbox");
            powershell.AddParameter("Identity", "username");
            powershell.AddParameter("Database", @"databasePath");
            var result = powershell.Invoke();
```